# JQuery & Java servlets : escaping special characters

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, servlets, character-encoding

I have an ajax get request to my server(where Text is my sentence I want to send to my server)

```
$.get("http://localhost:8080/myname/MyServlet?actn=InsertData&sentence="+Text,function(data){ });
```

And in my MyServlet class I have the function InsertData and there I print the sentence i've sent from the $.get call

```
public String InsertData(String Sentence)
{
      System.out.println(Sentence);
      ...........
      ...........

}
```

The problem is if for example im sending the sentence :

**The stock’s rise has boosted Zuckerberg’s wealth to $34.5 billion, according to the Bloomberg Billionaires Index.**

The output in **InsertData** :

**The stock?s rise has boosted Zuckerberg?s wealth to $34.5 billion, according to the Bloomberg Billionaires Index.**

Another example for the problem :

**Facebook shares had already jumped 81 percent in the 12 months through Sept. 5, compared with a 21 percent increase for the S&P 500.**

The output in **InsertData** :

**Facebook shares had already jumped 81 percent in the 12 months through Sept. 5, compared with a 21 percent increase for the S**

I tried using encodeURIComponent but it doesn't solve it.
I tried to use UTF-8 decoding on the servlets but it doesn't solve either.

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode your `Text` string. You may use [encodeURIComponent(Text)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent). So try this:

```
$.get("http://localhost:8080/myname/MyServletactn=InsertData&sentence="+encodeURIComponent(Text),function(data){ });
```

Comment: I already mentioned I tried it but it doesn't work. If i use the encodedURIComponent , for my first example, I get the following string on my Server : The stock???s rise has boosted Zuckerberg???s wealth to $34.5 billion, according to the Bloomberg Billionaires Index

Comment: @ranifisch Then it is not the problem of data, rather its the problem of console where you are trying to print. By default console don't support UTF-8 encoding. Try printing the data in a UTF-8 file to confirm.

Comment: I printed it but i still get weird result. the String I get in the function is : The stockâs rise has boosted Zuckerbergâs wealth to $34.5 billion, according to the Bloomberg Billionaires Index. but i can't seem to get the original sentence ... @Juned Ahsan